# Divide barplot into "subsections" with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to divide my barplot into areas so that certain areas of the X-axis lie within those areas. I'll try to attach two photos. The one with the green line is the one I want to reproduce (but the green line is not important to me) and the other one is my plot I have now. (I hope this is the right board for this question, sorry if not)

```
t$anticodon <- as.character(t$anticodon)
t$anticodon <- factor(t$anticodon, levels=c("GCA", "GCT", "GCC", "GCG", "AGA", "AGG", "CGA",
                                            "CGT", "CGC", "CGG", "AAT", "AAC", "GAT", "GAC", "TGC", "TGT", "CAA",
                                            "CAG", "GAA", "GAG", "GGA", "GGT", "GGC", "GGG", "CAT", "CAC", "ATA",
                                            "ATT", "ATC", "TTA", "CTA", "CTT", "TTG", "CTC", "CTG", "AAA", "AAG",
                                            "ATG", "TTT", "TTC", "CCA", "CCT", "CCC", "CCG", "AGT", "TCA", "TCT",
                                            "AGC", "TCC", "TCG", "TAA", "TAG", "TGA", "ACA", "ACT", "ACC", "ACG",
                                            "TGG", "TAT", "TAC", "GTA", "GTT", "GTC","GTG", "NNN"))
```

"t" is the .csv and "anticodon" is the row I used.

To visualize the plot:

```
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(t, aes(t$anticodon, t$copy_Ae)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Anti Codons") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 16)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = t$copy_Ae), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, size = 6) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16))
```

"copy_Ae" contains the number of times an anticodon occurs.
I managed to have the same arrangement on the x-axis.

So I want to create an area with "Alanin" (and for the other ones as well) that covers the range GCA to GCG on the X-axis.

Thank you.[bottom picture is the one I want to reproduce. Top picture is mine, but without these "areas"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiaCX.png)

Edit: output of $dput(t):

```
> dput(t)
structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), anticodon = structure(c(30L, 54L, 
52L, 7L, 55L, 31L, 17L, 44L, 49L, 18L, 56L, 65L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 
21L, 19L, 22L, 58L, 53L, 11L, 59L, 32L, 60L, 57L, 25L, 20L, 26L, 
45L, 12L, 46L, 27L, 24L, 47L, 61L, 33L, 37L, 38L, 28L, 48L, 41L, 
36L, 42L, 63L, 43L, 2L, 40L, 64L, 50L, 3L, 5L, 51L, 13L, 1L, 
16L, 8L, 15L, 39L, 23L, 35L, 14L, 6L, 34L, 62L, 29L), .Label = c("AAA", 
"AAC", "AAG", "AAT", "ACA", "ACC", "ACG", "ACT", "AGA", "AGC", 
"AGG", "AGT", "ATA", "ATC", "ATG", "ATT", "CAA", "CAC", "CAG", 
"CAT", "CCA", "CCC", "CCG", "CCT", "CGA", "CGC", "CGG", "CGT", 
"CTA", "CTC", "CTG", "CTT", "GAA", "GAC", "GAG", "GAT", "GCA", 
"GCC", "GCG", "GCT", "GGA", "GGC", "GGG", "GGT", "GTA", "GTC", 
"GTG", "GTT", "NNN", "TAA", "TAC", "TAG", "TAT", "TCA", "TCC", 
"TCG", "TCT", "TGA", "TGC", "TGG", "TGT", "TTA", "TTC", "TTG", 
"TTT"), class = "factor"), codon = structure(c(20L, 53L, 31L, 
8L, 21L, 18L, 33L, 56L, 65L, 64L, 7L, 36L, 47L, 28L, 2L, 58L, 
35L, 24L, 46L, 27L, 42L, 1L, 37L, 41L, 5L, 50L, 38L, 4L, 60L, 
55L, 14L, 44L, 6L, 26L, 54L, 40L, 15L, 23L, 57L, 12L, 49L, 29L, 
3L, 19L, 43L, 62L, 48L, 17L, 30L, 32L, 16L, 61L, 59L, 39L, 11L, 
45L, 25L, 9L, 10L, 34L, 13L, 22L, 63L, 51L, 52L), .Label = c("GCA", 
"GCT", "GCC", "GCG", "AGA", "AGG", "CGA", "CGT", "CGC", "CGG", 
"AAT", "AAC", "GAT", "GAC", "TGC", "TGT", "CAA", "CAG", "GAA", 
"GAG", "GGA", "GGT", "GGC", "GGG", "CAT", "CAC", "ATA", "ATT", 
"ATC", "TTA", "CTA", "CTT", "TTG", "CTC", "CTG", "AAA", "AAG", 
"ATG", "TTT", "TTC", "CCA", "CCT", "CCC", "CCG", "AGT", "TCA", 
"TCT", "AGC", "TCC", "TCG", "TAA", "TAG", "TGA", "ACA", "ACT", 
"ACC", "ACG", "TGG", "TAT", "TAC", "GTA", "GTT", "GTC", "GTG", 
"NNN"), class = "factor"), copy_Ae = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 98L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 32L, 10L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 
4L, 7L, 1L, 11L, 39L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), copy_Lf = c(6L, 
3L, 2L, 8L, 14L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 
3L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 99L, 9L, 14L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 10L, 
4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", "anticodon", "codon", "copy_Ae", 
"copy_Lf"), row.names = c(NA, -65L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Max, if you could add a part of you data it would help a lot. And i think in the picture the user used some sort of geom_rect.

Comment: I don't have much more data. The .csv file consists out of 3 rows (the "anticodon" row = GCA, GCT etc. | The other 2 rows contain the number of anticodons (GCA, GCT etc.) for 2 species). But maybe geom_rect is the right one. I have to look it up

Comment: you give a code that can't be executed with the data you give. Your data only contains `t$anticodon`, while your plot make use of `t$copy_Ae`. Please give the entire data that allow people to reproduce your plot

Comment: No problem, just use `dput(t)` and copy the result into your question. Also here is more useful information to how to ask questions here. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've added the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is still missing the grouping for the rectangles. So I took them from the your example and calculated it but it doesn't align, I guess because its a different type.
Hope it is helpful.

```
tlabel <- read.table(text="Alanine 4 0
Arginine 6 0
Asparagine 2 90
Aspartate 2 90
Cysteine 2 90
Glutamate 2 90
Glycine 5 0
Histidine 2 90
Isoleucine 3 90
Leucine 6 0
Lysine 2 0
Methoinine 1 90
Phenylalanine 2 90
Proline 3 0
Serine 6 0
STOP 3 0
Threonine 4 0
Tryptophan 1 90
Tyrosine 2 90
Valine 4 0", sep=" ", stringsAsFactor=F)

tlabel$V2[1] <- tlabel$V2[1]+0.5 
tlabel$end <- cumsum(tlabel$V2)
tlabel$start <- tlabel$end - tlabel$V2
tlabel$start[1] <- 0.5


ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=t, aes(anticodon, copy_Ae),stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(data=t, aes(anticodon, copy_Ae, label = copy_Ae), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, size = 6) +
  geom_rect(data=tlabel, aes(xmin=start,
                             xmax=end, 
                             ymin=0,ymax=110), fill=NA, color="black")+
  geom_text(data=tlabel, aes((end-start)/2+start, 80, label = V1), 
            size = 2, angle=tlabel$V3) +
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Anti Codons") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 16))
```

[image]